# Docker ENV command no longer valid when using docker run

Tags: android, docker

I am trying to build an Android application within a Docker container, but I'm having trouble setting environment variables when call `docker run`.  I've created a `DockerFile` at `ci/Dockerfile` which looks like:

```
FROM centos
MAINTAINER Jonathan Maltz <my@email.com>

# Install Development Tools
RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"

# yum update
RUN yum -y update

# Install java (OpenJDK)
RUN yum -y install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel

# Install 32bit Library
RUN yum -y install glibc.i686
RUN yum -y install libstdc++.i686
RUN yum -y install glibc-devel.i686
RUN yum -y install zlib-devel.i686
RUN yum -y install ncurses-devel.i686
RUN yum -y install libX11-devel.i686
RUN yum -y install libXrender.i686

# Install Android SDK
RUN cd /usr/local/ && curl -L -O http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz && tar xf android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz

# Environment variables
ENV ANDROID_HOME /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

# Install Android tools
RUN android list sdk --all
RUN echo y | android update sdk --filter tool --no-ui --force -a
RUN echo y | android update sdk --filter platform-tool --no-ui --force -a
RUN echo y | android update sdk --filter platform --no-ui --force -a
RUN echo y | android update sdk --filter extra --no-ui --force -a

# Clean up
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
RUN yum clean all

WORKDIR /mounted/volume
CMD ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Then, in a makefile, I have a target called test which is simply:

```
docker build -t my/container ci
docker run -v $(shell pwd):/mounted/volume my/container
```

When I run `make test` the container is properly configured, but when `gradlew assembleDebug` is run, I get the error message "The SDK directory '/Users/maltz/android-sdk' does not exist."  This is confusing, because that is the path to my local android SDK installation, not the `ANDROID_HOME` I configured in the `Dockerfile`.

So, my question is: why doesn't `docker run` respect the `ANDROID_HOME` value that I set in my `DockerFile`? And, as a follow-up, how should I configure my `Dockerfile`/`Makefile` so that my commands reference the correct environment variables within the container.

Comment: what happens when you run `docker run -v $(shell pwd):/mounted/volume my/container env` can you see the value for `ANDROID_HOME`?

Comment: if `gradlew` is a script can you either post it or add a link to the code?

Comment: `gradlew` is the gradle wrapper that comes when you add a wrapper task to gradle.  It downloads a version of gradle that you've specified in `gradle.properties`.  The error is happening with the android plugin for Gradle, which expects to have some way to reference your android SDK.

Comment: As for the `docker run` command.  If I specify `./gradlew assembleDebug` in the `Dockerfile`, the environment variables are handled correctly.  However, when I don't specify them, those environment variables are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your project `$(shell pwd):/mounted/volume` folder mounted into container contains `local.properties` file which overrides environment variable. It contains something like this

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Tue Mar 28 17:07:37 CEST 2017
sdk.dir=/Users/maltz/android-sdk
```

You would have to delete it first.